# Angular - Display user details on dashboard after Login

Tags: angular, laravel, api

I am using Angular 7 and Laravel 5.8 to create user Login. Laravel serves the end point to Angular. I successfully created the user login, but I don't know how to display the logged in username

user.ts

```
export class User {
id?: number;
name?: string;
email?: string;
password?: string;
username?: string;

constructor() {}
```

}

auth.service

```
  onLogin(user: User): Observable<User> {

const request = JSON.stringify(
  { email: user.email, password: user.password }
);

return this.http.post(this.loginUrl, request, httpOptions)
  .pipe(
    map((response: User) => {
      // Receive jwt token in the response
      const token: string = response['access_token'];
      // If we have a token, proceed
      if (token) {
        this.setToken(token);
        this.getUser().subscribe();
      }
      return response;
    }),
    catchError(error => this.handleError(error))
  );
 }
```

login.component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { SnotifyService } from 'ng-snotify';
import { Ng4LoadingSpinnerService } from 'ng4-loading-spinner';
import { NotificationService } from '../../services/notification.service';

onSubmit(loginForm): void {
this.spinnerService.show();
this.authService.onLogin(this.user).subscribe(
  (response) => {     

    this.notify.success('Done, you have successfully logged in.', {timeout:2000, position: "rightTop"})        
    this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);      
  },
  (error) => {
    this.spinnerService.hide();
    this.error = error.error;
  }
);
// Clear form fields
loginForm.reset();
}
```

dashboard.component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {dashboard2} from "src/assets/dist/js/pages/dashboard2.js";
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { User } from '../../models/user';

declare var $;

@Component({
selector: 'app-dashboard',
templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

ngOnInit() {

window.dispatchEvent(new Event('load'));
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));

$(dashboard2);
document.body.className = 'skin-blue sidebar-mini';
}
ngOnDestroy(): void {
document.body.className = '';
}

}
```

After the dashboard component then you have the dashboard html

dashboard.html

```html
      <div class="jumbotron">
          <div class="text-center">
            <h1 class="display-3">Dashboard</h1>
            <!-- <p class="lead">This is the sample dashboard, you can find all books in book tab.</p> -->
          </div>
          <hr class="my-4">
          <div class="card">
            <h3 class="card-header text-center">Your Information</h3>
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">

            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
```

So, how do I make the user detail like user login email to appear on the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to store the user detail somewhere. For example a service or a store. This is typically done during login and the dashboard component will retrieve the user detail.

1. Service
   You may create a service with at least 2 methods: setUserDetail and getUserDetail
2. Store/State management
   There are ngrx, a4-reducer, NGXS, Akita, etc.

Comment: PLease can you give me sample based on my available code